# KendoUI grid if field is true/false change title

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a boolean isActive that returns TRUE or FALSE

```
           {
                field: "isActive",
                title: "Status",
                width: 90

            }
```

I've managed to make this work and in the grid it will show 'true' or 'false'. However I want to make it if its true, change field to A and if false change title to B. How can I do this?

EDIT: This is how they are written usually (field,title, width, template etc). IsActive is a boolean, and I want it to perform a check (if isActive = true, return A. Not sure how to explain it. Currently it its displaying the boolean value (true/false) and I want it to display Active/Inactive in the grid. Sorry for the confusion, the title will remained unchanged

Comment: What is *field*? What is *A*? Which *title*? When do you want to check? On change? Periodically? Be more specific + provide more code.

Comment: Try to edit your question rather than adding this as a comment to improve the quality of your question. You can delete the comment afterwards (even with low rep I guess)

Comment: okay thanks! hopefully someone understands what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I think you can get that done with a hash template. Try something like field: "#= isActive == 'true' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' #" Otherwise you might be able to just use a javascript function. You may need to debug to see what isActive is stored as. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a column template function (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template):

```
{ field: "isActive",
  template: function(dataItem){
      return dataItem.isActive ? "Active" : "Inactive";
  }
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/EKeGA)**

Comment: Of the three answers here, this is the only one I was able to get to work

Answer (score 1):

I think that better solution could be:

```
{
    field: "isActive",
    title: "Status"
    values: [{ text: 'Yes', value: true }, { text: 'No', value: false }]
}
```

it also enables combo box in filters

Answer (score 0):

use  template

```
 { field: "isActive", title: "isActive", template: "#= isActive ? 'Yes' : 'No' #", width: "100px" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag Helper Solution which covers all the bases.

```
@{
    var yesNoValues = new object[] { new { Text = "Yes", Value = true }, new { Text = "No", Value = false } };
}

<kendo-grid name="grid">
<columns>
<foreign-key-column field="isActive" template="#=template(data)#" values='@yesNoValues' value-field="Value" text-field="Text"></foreign-key-column>
...

<script>
    function template(dataItem) {
        return dataItem.isActive== true ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
</script>
```